# Linked Lists Confusion

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, traversal

I have been looking at the same section of this book for the past few days, and cannot seem to figure out how the field of this linked list/structure changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dvdTracker.h"


/**************************************************> main <*/
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char            command;

    gHeadPtr = NULL;
    gTailPtr = NULL;

    while ( (command = GetCommand() ) != 'q' ) {
        switch( command ) {
            case 'n':
                AddToList( ReadStruct() );
                break;
            case 'l':
                ListDVDs();
                break;
        }
    }

    printf( "Goodbye..." );

    return 0;
}


/*******************************************> GetCommand <*/
char    GetCommand( void )
{
    char    command;

    do {
        printf( "Enter command (q=quit, n=new, l=list):  " );
        scanf( "%c", &command );
        Flush();
    }
    while ( (command != 'q') && (command != 'n')
           && (command != 'l') );

    printf( "\n----------\n" );
    return( command );
}


/*******************************************> ReadStruct <*/
struct DVDInfo  *ReadStruct( void ) {
    struct DVDInfo  *infoPtr;
    int             num;

    infoPtr = (struct DVDInfo *)malloc( sizeof( struct DVDInfo ) );

    if ( NULL == infoPtr ) {
        printf( "Out of memory!!!  Goodbye!\n" );
        exit( 0 );
    }

    printf( "Enter DVD Title:  " );
    fgets( infoPtr->title, kMaxTitleLength, stdin );
    ReplaceReturnAtEndOfString( infoPtr->title );

    printf( "Enter DVD Comment:  " );
    fgets( infoPtr->comment, kMaxCommentLength, stdin );
    ReplaceReturnAtEndOfString( infoPtr->comment );

    do {
        num = 0;
        printf( "Enter DVD Rating (1-10):  " );
        scanf( "%d", &num );
        Flush();
    }
    while ( ( num < 1 ) || ( num > 10 ) );

    infoPtr->rating = num;

    printf( "\n----------\n" );

    return( infoPtr );
}


/*******************************************> AddToList <*/
void    AddToList( struct DVDInfo *curPtr ) {
    if ( NULL == gHeadPtr )
        gHeadPtr = curPtr;
    else
        gTailPtr->next = curPtr;

    gTailPtr = curPtr;
    curPtr->next = NULL;
}


/*******************************************> ListDVDs <*/
void    ListDVDs( void ) {
    struct DVDInfo  *curPtr;

    if ( NULL == gHeadPtr ) {
        printf( "No DVDs have been entered yet...\n" );
        printf( "\n----------\n" );
    } else {
        for ( curPtr=gHeadPtr; curPtr!=NULL; curPtr = curPtr->next ) {
            printf( "Title:  %s\n", curPtr->title );
            printf( "Comment:   %s\n", curPtr->comment );
            printf( "Rating:  %d\n", curPtr->rating );

            printf( "\n----------\n" );
        }
    }
}
```

When I am debugging this program, at the line:

gTailPtr->next=curPtr;

gHeadPtr->next also points to the current pointer, though I don't see how.

This is from Learning C on Mac (Addison) page 256, and if someone can help, thanks! Or explain at least.

Comment: In this case, how helping is different than explaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the second item being inserted into the list, then `gTailPtr` and `gHeadPtr` will initially point at the same node (the first, and only, node in the list).  So, at this point,  `gTailPtr->next` and `gHeadPtr->next` are just two names for the same object.

The key thing to understand is that `gHeadPtr` isn't a node itself, and doesn't contain a `next` field at all.  It's just a *pointer* to a node: this means that what it contains is a reference to some node (or no node at all).  When you assign to `gHeadPtr` itself, you are changing *which node it points to*.  When you use the `->` operator, you are examining the node that it points to right now.

Think of it like this: A pointer variable is like a scrap of paper that can have a phone number written on it.  When you change the pointer variable, this is like erasing the phone number and replacing it with a different one; when you use the `->` operator, this is like calling the phone number.  Two pointers variables that point to the same node is just like having two pieces of paper with the same phone number written on them: it doesn't matter which one you use to call, you'll reach the same destination.  A `NULL` pointer is a blank piece of paper: trying to call that number just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is there any way you can elaborate a little more? Like, if there is another way to write the code? I sort of know what you mean, but I still don't understand when gHeadPtr's next field was set.

Comment: @Jon Wei: I've added some more.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I do understand up to the point that gHeadPtr and gTailPtr are just pointer variables. gHeadPtr just points to your first struct's fields, and when calling it to write out the list, curPtr points to gHeadPtr, which then can be used to access the fields of what it points to (infoPtr). The only thing I can't grasp from your explanation is how you said:

gHeadPtr->next and gTailPtr->next are pointing to the same object. So are they after the second add to the list, but why doesn't gHeadPtr's next change at the third add? Sorry if this sonds confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a double headed linked list. You can use it as both queue(first in first out), and as stack(last in first out). The pointer gHeadPtr is for popping the first element inserted and gTailPtr is popping the last element inserted. Think about when the list is blank. Both gHeadPtr and gTailPtr are null. Now the condition to find out if the list is blank is `if ( NULL == gHeadPtr )`. So when first element is to be inserted, you point the curPtr to the gHeadPtr. Once inserted, until you need to pop the first element there is no need to touch the gHeadPtr. For the first time even gTailPtr will point to curPtr. So when only one element is inserted both gHeadPtr and gTailPtr are pointed to the same element. When next element is inserted, gHeadPtr is untouched. The new element is added next to the gTailPtr and gTailPtr will point to new element. This is pretty much basic stuff about queue. Better to study about the data structures.